# Finding irreducible polynomial for isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am struggling to understand the approach to take in the following question:

*Consider the subfields $ K_1 = \mathbb{Q} $ and $ K_2 = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt5)$ of $ \mathbb{C} $.
 Find monic irreducible polynomials $ f_1 and f_2 ∈ Q[x]$ so that $ K_i \cong Q[x] / (f_i) $*

I understand that $ Q[x] / (f_i) $ is a field extension but I have no idea how to start going about finding the irreducible polynomial which gives $ Q[x] / (f_i) $ the same characteristics as $ K_i $.

Any help or a sample answer greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem: If $p(x)$ is irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ and $K/F$ is some extension s.t. $\alpha \in K$ is a root of $p$, i.e. $p(\alpha) = 0$, then $F[x]/(p(x)) \cong F(\alpha)$.

For a proof see e.g. see Dummit and Foote 13.1.

This should give you a way to find the right polynomials.

Comment: Thanks, so the polynomials will have to have a root at 0 and $sqrt(5)$ respectively?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}(r) = \mathbb{Q}$ for any $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. But those would work. Note the irreducibility condition too.

Comment: So would $f _1 = x $ and $f_2 = x^2 - 5 $ work, as these are both irreducible in $ \mathbb{Q} $ ?

Comment: Yes, those would work.